# Remove all non-essential json formatting in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's say I have some convoluted json like so:

```json
{
  "ref": "some",
  "repository": {
    "id": 123456789,
    "name": "foo bar"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it into this format:

```
{"ref":"some","repository":{"id":123456789,"name":"foo bar"}}
```

So, no whitespace or newlines except the ones in the json key/value pairs themselves.

`Regex.Replace(myJson, @"\s+", string.Empty)` removes the spaces from `foo bar` resulting in `foobar`.

Using

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJson, Formatting.None)`

Gives me

`{\n    \"ref\": \"some\",\n    \"repository\": {\n      \"id\": 123456789,\n      \"name\": \"foo bar\"\n    }\n}`

What's another way I can remove all non-essential white spaces and newlines on this json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always deserialize your json into an object then reserialize it. Without providing any options, the default result is in line with what you're looking for.

```
    var rawJson = @"{
  ""ref"": ""some"",
  ""repository"": {
    ""id"": 123456789,
    ""name"": ""foo bar""
  }
}";
    var tempObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawJson);
    var inlineJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempObj);
```

The output of that is `{"ref":"some","repository":{"id":123456789,"name":"foo bar"}}`

Comment: Any performance implications when doing this with large objects?

Comment: Probably, but without a concrete example it's hard to assess.

Answer (score 2):

```
JToken.FromObject(yourObject).ToString(Formatting.None);
```

This removes all new lines and white space outside of property values.